# Add URL Paramter to Document Library

Tags: document, parameter

I have a document library with folders.

I am currently using a filter querystring on a list to show a specific menu on the page layout.

When a user clicks a folder on the page it drops the parameter and I get the entire list.

I want to change the document library so that it always adds &Parameter=X on the links for folders so that the querystring filters on the page remain intact.  X is preferably a querystring filter I can bind to the library.

I am not a JS programmer so the easier the solution the better.

How do I modify just this document library display on this page to achieve this?

SharePoint Office 365 E3 Instance